# User photo showing on my Google business / map

Tags: google-maps, google-my-business-api

I noticed that when i gooogle my business : "cafe mums fredericia".
A user uploaded photo shows up, right to my business url

Is there a way to change it, so that it shows the photos i would like / uploaded?

Also - how can i set it up, so that users can´t overwrite my uploadet business / photos / images.

Really hope you can help

Cheers 
C yaaa

Kimo

Comment: I believe you should address this question to Google My Business support team: https://support.google.com/business#topic=4539639&contact=1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programmatic  issue.

Comment: Hi there - Thanks. I´ll close this question at once.

Comment: If you own the business you should be able to administer the photos that show for your business. You can always report the picture(s) if you feel they don't do any good to your place.

Comment: Hi there - Hmm.. i cant seem to remove the user uploadet picture.
The photo is taken in the café, so that part is okay, but i rather that it was my own photos that where on google maps / as start picture.

Thanks -
C yaaa